# How to test Stripe Payout webhook

Tags: stripe-payments, payout

In testing mode, is there a way to force a payout to happen with a payment that was done today?
I know that in normal operation, a payout for a payment recieved today will happen 7 days from now, but I can't wait 7 days during integration testing to have the payment show up and result in a payout.

I am testing my code that handles the payout details and I need to create some payments, then create a payout and then run my code to make sure I am handling the details of the payout properly, without having to wait 7 days between payment and testing.

Is there a way to speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

Currently no way to speed this up unfortunately. However if you set the correct, real bank account once and for all, then after 7 days your account should be good enough to run any tests.